# "the ____ of which"-artiger Relativsatz in Deutsch möglich?

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clause, relative-pronoun

Auf Englisch kann man sagen:

> "The new system, **the** effectiveness **of which** is obvious,..."

statt

> "**whose** effectiveness".

Auf Deutsch würde ich es so ausdrücken:

> "Das System, dessen Effektivität..."

Die Form mit "the" und "of which" Kann ich im Englischen nutzen um solch einen Satz zu bilden:

> "The only alternative would be to rewrite the software entirely, **the** cost **of which** would be very high.",

also um einen Relativsatz zu bilden, der sich auf etwas abstraktes, also das Rewriting der Software, statt auf ein explizites Nomen bezieht.

Ist es im Deutschen möglich, zu diesem Zweck einen Relativsatz zu bilden, in dem vor dem Pronomen ein weiteres Nomen steht, wie vor "of which"?

> (?) "Die einzige Alternative wäre, die Software komplett neu zu schreiben, die Kosten wessen/dessen ..."
> (Hier habe ich das Gefühl, kein passendes Relativpronomen finden zu können.)

oder sollte es eher so formuliert werden:

> (?)"...neu zu schreiben, wessen/dessen Kosten sehr hoch wären".

(Hier habe ich allerdings auch das Gefühl, dass es nicht möglich ist, weil sich das Relativpronomen auf ein Nomen beziehen muss, welches nicht vorhanden ist.)

Sind solche Relativsätze zumindest möglich um ein konkretes Nomen zu beschreiben?

> "Die Statue, die Schönheit welcher nicht in Frage steht."?

Answer (score 4):

> Die einzige Alternative wäre, die Software komplett neu zu schreiben, wessen Kosten sehr hoch wären.

ist in meinen Augen nicht ungrammatisch, aber nicht idiomatisch - was für deine Frage aufs Selbe hinausläuft.

Es gibt also keine im Deutschen übliche Möglichkeit, der Relativsatz ist nicht als solcher übersetzbar, man muss eine andere Form finden, die das Gleiche oder zumindest etwas Ähnliches ausdrückt:

> Die einzige Alternative wäre, die Software komplett neu zu schreiben. Die Kosten dessen wären sehr hoch.

> Die einzige Alternative wäre, die Software komplett neu zu schreiben, wobei die Kosten sehr hoch wären.

---

Das Relativpronomen steht im Relativseatz an erster Stelle.

> <strike>Die Statue, die Schönheit welcher nicht in Frage steht.</strike>

ist daher ungrammatisch. Richtig wäre hier aber:

> Die Statue, deren Schönheit  nicht in Frage steht.

Comment: Wie sieht es mit dem letzten Beispielsatz meiner Frage aus? Sind Relativsätze im Genitiv, bei denen ein Nomen vor dem Pronomen steht, generell ungrammatisch?

Comment: @JMC Es ist üblich, für jede Frage einen eigenen Thread zu starten. Das ist auch oft sinnvoll. Im konkreten Fall hatte ich die zweite Frage gar nicht so richtig als relevante Frage wahrgenommen. Ich habs jetzt eben beantwortet, um nicht krümelkackerisch zu sein. Aber vielleicht in Zukunft dran denken... :)

Comment: Die Frage, ob diese Wortreihenfolge möglich ist, sollte eigentlich die Hauptfrage sein. Der Grund warum ich diese Formulierung benötigte, war, dass ich davon ausging, dass ein Relativsatz, der sich auf etwas Abstraktes bezieht genau dann möglich wäre, was allerdings nicht der Fall zu sein scheint. Ich hab es etwas umformuliert und werde nächstes mal drauf achten.

Answer (score 1):

Soweit ich weiß, muß ein Relativsatz von einem Relativpronomen eingeleitet werden. Vorangehen kann höchstens eine Präposition. Eine Kombination von Relativartikel und Nomen *(deren Schönheit)* verhält sich wie ein Relativpronomen.

In der Sprachwissenschaft wird das Phänomen, daß Relativ- oder Interrogativpronomen bei Voranstellung noch etwas "mitnehmen" können, als [Pied Piping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied-piping) (deutsch [Rattenfängerkonstruktion](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rattenf%C3%A4ngerkonstruktion)) bezeichnet.

Das Englische ist in dieser Hinsicht maximal flexibel:

> a topic **which** I would like to have *a discussion about*
> a topic **about which** I would like to have *a discussion*
> a topic **a discussion about which** I would like to have

Das Deutsche dagegen beschränkt:

> *ein Thema, das ich ein Gespräch über führen möchte
> ein Thema, über das ich ein Gespräch führen möchte
> *ein Thema, ein Gespräch über das ich führen möchte

Man sieht, daß das Bild des Rattenfängers für das Englische Sinn zu ergeben scheint: Zur Bildung eines Relativsatzes muß mindestens das Pronomen vorangestellt werden, welches aber andere Elemente nachziehen kann. (Am schönsten natürlich der wunderbare Beispielsatz in allen seinen Varianten aus der [Dissertation](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/15166) von [Haj Ross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_R._Ross) selbst: *reports which the government prescribes the height of the lettering on the covers of*.)

Im Deutschen ist das schon schwieriger: Um die Ungrammatikalität des ersten Satzes zu erklären, muß man *pied piping* als unter bestimmten Bedingungen obligatorisch ansehen; um die des letzten Satzes zu erklären, muß man die Möglichkeiten von *pied piping* beschränken.